# A non-constructive proof of definability

Tags: model-theory, math-history

In the mathematical literature, specifically in model theory, has there ever been a proof that some function, relation, or constant in some structure is definable from the structure, without actually exhibiting a definition, even an abbreviated definition? That is, the proof proves that it is definable, without actually giving a definition, even an abbreviated definition.

Comment: A "cheating" example would be something like consider the structure $(\mathbb Q,{+},{\times})$, and define _at the metalevel_ $$ x = \begin{cases} 1\in\mathbb Q & \text{if the Riemann Hypothesis is true} \\ 0\in\mathbb Q & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ We know that $x$ is first-order definable because every element of our structure is, but we don't know what the definition is.

Comment: The relevance of this example is that of course we'll want to exclude such cheating, but it seems to be hard to nail down exactly what constitutes "cheating" and how a "non-cheating" example could look like. Certainly in order to prove the _existence_ of a definition for something at the metalevel, we'd need to have defined _somehow_ at the metalevel which object it is we're talking about. That definition needs to live at the metalevel, but somehow we'll still need to forbid definitions that talk about the Riemann Hypothesis, and I can't see how to draw such a line.

Comment: (In fact my attempt at cheating doesn't work, since it turns out that [$\mathbb N$ is first-order definable](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19852) in $(\mathbb Q,{+},{\times})$, which we can use to write down one of the known all-integer equivalents of the RH. I should have used a simpler structure, such a finite set with constants symbols for each element ...)

Comment: In some sense, this happens all the time in model theory. Here are two examples: In a saturated structure $M$, (1) an element $a$ is fixed by all automorphisms of $M$ if and only if $\{a\}$ is definable, (2) if a set $X$ and its complement $M\setminus X$ are both type-definable, then they are in fact both definable. In both cases, the proof rests on a (non-constructive) compactness argument, which fails to give an explicit definition.

Comment: If this answers your question, I can try to dig up some explicit examples and turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman -- If you don't mind, I'm not OP but would love to see an explicit example of what you're suggesting.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, it answers the question. You can give me an explicit answer.